# Understanding FFT for a sinusoid

Tags: python, audio, window, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to understand how FFT works.

If I plot the FFT of this signal (i.e. np.abs(fft(y)), I see one peak at 10 Hz as expected.
My experiment is to alter the last value of y (i.e. y[-1] = 0) so that the signal y does not seem to connect smoothly when repeated, but the output does not change:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJL78.png)

My understanding is that there will be a leakage in the FFT plot since FFT will "think" that the signal is not smoothly connected together at around 1 second. However, I do not see the leakage at all. Am I missing something critical?

Comment: Do you mean 'the last value of y'? y will be a float in the range -1 to 1 because it is the cos of something. y[-1] refers to a data structure that is not in your code. Why do you not edit your question to clarify.

Comment: “I do not see the leakage at all”. What do you see then? Changing a value in the input array must change the output. If you don’t see a change at all, maybe you are looking at something different than you think? Why not post full code that reproduces the plots you are looking at?

Comment: See how the red dots are not lined up with the 0 on the Y axis?  That's your "leakage"

Answer (score 1):

Sample points must be power of 2. I would recommed you to work at least 4 times higher number of points. Which makes 10Hertz x4 = 40 points, closest power of 2 is 64 poins.

Comment: No need to have a power of two number of samples.